# Apache HTTPD - AliasMatch and ProxyPass in Virtualhost

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have backend API which like this :

```
http://192.168.65.203:2022/page/index.jsp
```

and i have Apache httpd server as a 1st layer before hit backend. I set the port as 8090.

Now i want for image file will only get from httpd server, not from backend server. So my VirtualHost look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off
<Directory "/usr/share/myfile">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
AliasMatch ^/(.*\.gif|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg|.*\.png|.*\.css|.*\.swf)$ /usr/share/myfile/$1
ProxyPass / http://192.168.65.203:2022/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.65.203:2022/
```

Problem : image still pickup from backend server. If i disable proxypass and proxypassreserve, it working fine (image can load from httpd server).

Expectation : how i can control if image is found (at alias rule) it should not go for proxypass? or is there any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directive ! is needed. Below is the solution for my problem..

```
<VirtualHost *:8090>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off
<Directory "/usr/share/myfile">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/usr/share/myfile"
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.gif|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg|.*\.png|.*\.css|.*\.swf)$ !
ProxyPass / http://192.168.65.203:2022/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.65.203:2022/
</VirtualHost>
```

When the request is image type it will go to local file system "/usr/share/myfile" and the Directive ! is like to stop the proxy. Check [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for more details for this directive.

Answer (score 0):

Replace [1] by [2] and try:

```
[1] : 
AliasMatch ^/(.*\.gif|.*\.jpg|.*\.jpeg|.*\.png|.*\.css|.*\.swf)$ /usr/share/myfile/$1

[2] :
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.gif)$   !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.jpg)$   !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.jpeg)$  !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.png)$   !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.css)$   !
ProxyPassMatch ^/(*.swf)$   !
```

Comment: can you explain little bit on that? it will go to this directory "/usr/share/myfile/$1" if image?